# why does app.js call constructor every time i refresh page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to React so please bear with me.

I'm passing a callback from App.js to a child component which then sends the information back to App.js, using it to set the state in App.js. However, when I refresh the page, the state in App.js reverts to its original state (null). I realized the constructor was being called every time I hit refresh, so the updated state was being overwritten by the original state. Why does this happen because I thought constructor only runs once. How can I fix this issue so the updated state can persist even if I navigate to other pages or refresh?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless so every time the page is refreshed, the constructor is called for each component to set the initial state. To persist information across page reloads, you can use [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) which stores information in the browser. `localStorage` persists across page sessions unless specifically cleared. `sessionStorage` persists until the session ends.

**To store items:**

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

**To read items:**

```
let data = localStorage.getItem('foo');
```

**To clear items:**

```
// remove item with key 'foo'
localStorage.removeItem('foo');

//remove all items
localStorage.clear();
```

Note that the items are stored as strings so you should convert other datatypes into strings like so:

```
//store object
localStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify(myObject));

//read object
let myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object'));
```